Sorry, the installer has encountered an internal error ... Ubuntu server
Cannot install neither Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS or Ubuntu 24.10 on my Dell PowerEdge R630.
Can anyone help me please?


What happens when you try to install? Can you post the full error message?

how can I post a picture?

Upload to https://imgur.com/ and post the link here. Once you gain some reputation in the site, you will be able to post pictures directly

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mlwd01JRFr2Zxuxjcx4LFTvEc7BM4E1J/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17H1SCs2IdmDTl__8cRYeFyVnAiIZ6cnG/view?usp=sharing ... a small video

On the background of your screen, we see the failure:
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

This error suggests you are not connected to internet ;

Either connect to a network (Wifi or Ethernet)
You might be able to skip this step
Or, normally, Ubuntu should not even try if you indicated to not connect to the internet



If you want to deals with, and if it's a genuine network issue ;

Try changing your DNS by something else, such as 1.1.1.1
Check your network configuration :

Default route, using ip r

It should look like 192.168.x.x, 172.16.x.x, or 10.x.x.x


Your current IP, mask using ip a

192.168.x.x, 172.16.x.x, or 10.x.x.x for your IP address
192.168.x.255, 172.16.x.255, or 10.x.x.255 for the mask





You may show us the output of both ip r and ip a if my first suggestion didn't work.
You may also show us the output of:
$ nslookup archive.ubuntu.com # Test DNS resolve
$ ping -c 1 185.125.190.81 # Test ping using IP


In case you are wondering how to open a shell prompt ;
You should be able to open a shell at any moment with the graphical interface :

Or between each step of the non-graphical installation process.

Thanks Mike for your comment... the issue with internet didn't solve the problem as it was the same with normal internet connection (when mirror site was accepted by installer). I solved my problem by installing an old version of Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS 64 Bit that is certified for my server Dell PowerEdge R630 (https://ubuntu.com/certified/201901-26800) with no problem at all and after that I upgraded it to the latest release (https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/how-to-upgrade-your-release). So, there is a big issue with installer... at least it was with me (or my system is not compatible with ubuntu latest installer).
